# Why is my generator implementation incorrect in Python?

Tags: python, generator

So basically i am writing a program where i need to take in a file that contains uppercase letters, that may or may not be seperated by white space or new lines, and return a generator over the letters in the file.

For example:

```
Z FM
TM  CC
```

Would return a generator with an output of "Z","F","M","T","M","C","C"

The function should be a generator, so it will only load in letters at a time instead of the entire file.

Anyways, here is what i have so far. ANyone tell me where i went wrong?

```
def buildGen:
    with open(filename) as sample:
        for word in sample:
           for ch in word:
               yield ch
```

Comment: The indentation is wrong, code under `with` needs to be indented, and `dna` isn't defined, should probably be `sample`.

Comment: fixed it, doesnt do anything though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of problems with your code:

1. You're defining a function with the wrong syntax (`def buildGen:` <- Parenthesis should follow).
2. Your description of the output implies that you need to address whitespace characters.

The following outputs the output in your example (assuming your file is `stuff.txt`):

```
# Note `buildGen` takes now `filename`.
def buildGen(filename): 
    with open(filename) as sample:
        for word in sample:
           for ch in word:
               # Only yield non-whitespace.
               if ch.strip():
                   yield ch

print list(buildGen('stuff.txt'))
```

Comment: They "*may or may not be separated by newlines*" - if they aren't, then `for word in sample` will read the entire file in one go as one line.

Comment: Is there a way that i can do this and save the contents to a list in the same function?

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler That's a good point. Iterating over `open(filename).read()` would work whether there are newlines or not, but, of course, that loads up everything (which sort of defeats the purpose of a generator, to some extent).

Comment: @Team.Coco If you know that you'll end up storing everything in a list, there are easier ways to go about it then a generator (which has the benefit that you can process things not all at once). If you write a generator, though, then you have the flexibility of doing `list(buildGen('stuff.txt'))`, which turns it into a list.

Answer (score 0):

You are using wrong indentation and a wrong variable name dna. You need write something like this:

```
def buildGen:
    with open(filename) as sample:
        for line in sample.read().splitlines():
            for ch in line.split():
                yield ch
```

Comment: `def buildGen:` gives `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`.

Comment: That works somewhat. Is there a way that i can yield it into a generator AND save the contents to a list in the same method?

Answer (score 0):

Assume only `uppercase letters` will be included in the output and `only load in letters at a time instead of the entire file`:

```
def buildGen():
    with open(filename) as sample:
        while True:
            ch = sample.read(1)
            if ch:
                if 'A' <= ch <= 'Z':
                    yield ch
            else:
                break
```

Answer (score -1):

your logic here is wrong, as according to my understanding you are trying to read the file and yield all the letters in the file by calling your `buildGen` function.

As you are using a with statement it will close the file each time and you always end up with the first line only. Another point is you are opening the file as sample and using as dna that itself will throw an error.

you can achieve the same using this

```
fp = open('sample.txt')
# generator for the data
data_generator = (c for c in fp.read())
for char in data_generator:
    print char


def read_chars(fp):
    for line in fp
```

Comment: "*The function should be a generator, so it will only load in letters at a time instead of the entire file.*" - `fp.read()` will load the entire file all in one go.